# How do I emit signal while clicking TableViewColumn?

Tags: treeview, qml, tableview, qt5, qtquick2

I would like to add a `MouseArea`/`Button` to a `TableViewColumn` to perform specific tasks. However, if I add one of the above type, it overrides the "click" event of `TableViewColumn` so that I lose row selection.

Here is an example code. The row is not switching when I click it in the area of the last column:

```
TreeView { 
    clip: true id: mapsTreeView 
    objectName: "mapsTreeView" 
    model: theModel

    TableViewColumn {
        width: 100
        role: "name_role"
        title: "Map"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 50
        role: "description_role"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        id: imageColumn
        width: 20
        role: "image_role"
        delegate: Item {
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    mapsTreeView.sigChangeState()
                }
            }
            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                width: 5
                source: "icon" + styleData.value + ".png"
            }
        }

    }
    signal sigChangeState()
}
```

Comment: Is MouseArea.[`propagateComposedEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) what you are looking for? Not so clear the question, at least to me, sorry.

Comment: Thank u for the answer! It sound just what i need - but it doesn't work. Stiil TreeView doesn't change selection by click on the area, reloaded with the mouse area. i suppouse that property only includes mouse areas, and not treeView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but this works for me:

```
MouseArea {
   anchors.fill: parent

     onContainsPressChanged: {
        if(containsPress)
        {
            console.log("PRESSED")
        }
     }

     onPressed: {
        mouse.accepted = false
     }
}
```